# unable to prepare context: path not found - azure iot build and push vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, azure-iot-edge

I've been going through a microsoft tutorial on iot edge: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module?view=iotedge-2018-06" and followed each step. I've got to the part where i build and push IOT edge solution in vscode, however i have an error:

Unable to prepare context: path "EdgeSolution\modules\CModule" not found'.

I believe it's to do with the docker container, however i've checked the json documents and everthing seems correct and pointing to the correct module. Any ideas?

Below is a screenshot of the error:

[Terminal comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flAYx.png)

Thanks

Comment: I just followed the tutorial you linked to the letter, and I'm not facing that issue. Could you perhaps include a screenshot of the error? Is it occurring after you do the right-click and choose "Build and Push IoT Edge Solution"?

Comment: Thank you for your time. i've added the screenshot to the original post. Yes it's when i right click on the deployment.template.json and click build and push iot edge solution.

Comment: I'm using a windows 10 pc and the default iot edge solution in vscode is amd64, is this causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for updating. Seems to be a Docker issue, you could try running `docker build` manually, to see if the same error occurs.

Comment: Nathen, is your issue solved? Matthijs I would suggest you convert the comments to the answer to this thread.